# Google Cloud Build unable to fetch firebase for function deployment

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-build

I have the following very small cloudbuild.yaml file:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/myproject/firebase'
  args:
  - deploy
  - --only functions
  - --project=myproject
```

I also setup a cloud build trigger to run whenever I push a change to my repo. Builds trigger succesfully however, in the logs I see the following:

> Pulling image: gcr.io/myproject/firebase Using default tag: latest
> Error response from daemon: Head
> "https://gcr.io/v2/myproject/firebase/manifests/latest": name unknown:
> Repository "gcr.io" not found

The build retries precisely 10 times and ends with the following error:

> ERROR: failed to pull because we ran out of retries. ERROR ERROR:
> build step 0 "gcr.io/myproject/firebase" failed: error pulling
> build step 0 "gcr.io/myproject/firebase": generic::unknown: retry
> budget exhausted (10 attempts): step exited with non-zero status: 1

When I trigger the deployment locally with the following command it works fine :

```
firebase deploy --only functions
```

So I suspect I'm missing something with the `yaml` config and where the firebase functions are being fetched from.

Comment: Did you push your image to gcr.io/myproject/firebase? (I have my doubts)

Comment: @ravenwing I did not.  but that's supposed to be the firebase tool that actually helps deploy no?

Comment: But is you project ID really `myproject`?
https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/learn-more#project-id

Comment: @ravenwing no its not I changed it on the question to highlight that it is my project id.